# What models and algorithms are used in commercial vehicle re-identification tasks?

Tags: image-recognition, image-processing

Due to the fast-growing applications of AI technologies applied to *vehicle re-identification* tasks, there have already been hot contests, such as the Nvidia AI challenge.

What algorithms or models are really adopted in commercial vehicle re-identification tasks, effective and reliable, nowadays?